# Efficiently converting combination of pandas dataframe column into key-value pair

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and wish to convert it to key value pair:
My dataframe:

```
Institution    Funding
ETH             WTO
Harbin        WTO, CASA, WHO
SJSU          NASA, WTO
JAIST           NASA
```

If I had single entry in the "Funding" Column. I was able to achieve it with built-ins like this:

```
dict(zip(df['Funding'], df['Institution']))
```

But, with more complicated case (with multiple entries and comma's and white space). This doesn't work.
What can be done?  (also ideally I would like to use all the distinct entries in Funding column. For details: see the dataframe above and expected output below)

Expected output:

```
{'ETH': {'WTO':True, 'CASA': False, 'WHO': False, 'NASA': False},
'Harbin': {'WTO':True, 'CASA': True, 'WHO': True, 'NASA': False},
'SJSU': {'WTO':True, 'CASA': False, 'WHO': False, 'NASA': True},
'JAIST':{'WTO':False, 'CASA': False, 'WHO': False, 'NASA': True}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for index by `Institution`, select `Funding`, create dummies columns by [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), convert to boolean and then to nested dictionary by [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
d = (df.set_index('Institution')['Funding']
       .str.get_dummies(', ')
       .astype(bool)
       .to_dict('index'))
print (d)
{'ETH': {'CASA': False, 'NASA': False, 'WHO': False, 'WTO': True},
 'Harbin': {'CASA': True, 'NASA': False, 'WHO': True, 'WTO': True}, 
 'SJSU': {'CASA': False, 'NASA': True, 'WHO': False, 'WTO': True}, 
 'JAIST': {'CASA': False, 'NASA': True, 'WHO': False, 'WTO': False}}
```